# How to get the contents of the first `<li>` from `<ul>` with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

HTML like below

```
<div class="carousel"> 
  <div class="carousel_Wrapper"> 
    <div class="carousel_Container swiper-container"> 
      <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0001.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0002.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0003.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_NextBtn"></div> 
    <div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="carousel"> 
  <div class="carousel_Wrapper"> 
    <div class="carousel_Container swiper-container"> 
      <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0004.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0005.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0006.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_NextBtn"></div> 
    <div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

I would like to change to HTML like below using BeautifulSoup.

```
<figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0001.jpg"/></figure>
<p><a href="https://xxxx.jp">other photos</a></p>

<figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0004.jpg"/></figure>
<p><a href="https://xxxx.jp">other photos</a></p>
```

I'm thinking about removing unnecessary  in the following way. 
Since there may be other  s, we are specifying the class and doing decoponse (), unwrap ().

```
html = # First mentioned html

content = BeautifulSoup(html)

content.find('div', class_='carousel_NextBtn').decompose()
content.find('div', class_='carousel').unwrap()
content.find('div', class_='carousel_Wrapper').unwrap()
content.find('div', class_='carousel_Container swiper-container').unwrap()
```

When applying the above processing, I think that html as shown below will be generated.

```
<ul class="swiper-wrapper">
  <li class="swiper-slide"> 
    <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0001.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
  <li class="swiper-slide"> 
    <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0002.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
  <li class="swiper-slide"> 
    <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0003.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div> 

<ul class="swiper-wrapper">
  <li class="swiper-slide"> 
    <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0004.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
    <li class="swiper-slide"> 
  <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0005.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
    <li class="swiper-slide"> 
  <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0006.jpg"/></figure>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div>
```

We believe that the necessary processing is as follows from here.

- 1.Retrieve the content of the first `<li>` element of each `<ul>`
- 2.Insert `<p><a href="https://xxxx.jp">other photos</a></p>`

  For 2, I think that there is no problem by replacing  .
  But I do not know how to implement 1.

  Please show the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = """<div class="carousel"> 
  <div class="carousel_Wrapper"> 
    <div class="carousel_Container swiper-container"> 
      <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0001.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0002.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0003.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_NextBtn"></div> 
    <div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="carousel"> 
  <div class="carousel_Wrapper"> 
    <div class="carousel_Container swiper-container"> 
      <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0004.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0005.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
        <li class="swiper-slide"> 
          <figure><img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/0006.jpg"/></figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_NextBtn"></div> 
    <div class="carousel_PrevBtn"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
all_div = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'swiper-wrapper'})  # find all ul tag with specified class
for tag in all_div:
    print('-------------------- iteration : ' + str(all_div.index(tag)) + ' --------------------')
    print(tag.find('li', {'class': 'swiper-slide'}))  # this method works only if your item has class
    print(tag.contents[1])  # this method will also work if your item don't have a class
```

Your solution for "Retrieve the content of the first `<li>` element of each `<ul>`" can be achieved as shown in above code. you didn't face any problem for 2nd one so I haven't posted it yet. If you need any help on this let me know.